# nServiceBus used with sockets

Tags: c#, .net

I am fixing a .net app written on top of nServiceBus and have a few questions:

1. The app is configured AsA_Publisher and when it starts it waits for incoming
   connections on a socket, do you know why it might have been implemented like so?
   Why sockets? This socket is created during the Run method of a class which implements class IWantToRunAtStartup.
2. Once a message arrives, the message is written to a queue (Q1). The message
   is then read from the queue(Q1). The format of the message is changed and then
   inserted into yet another queue (Q2). The message is then read from the queue
   (Q2) and sent to another application by calling a web service. The whole idea is
   to change the message format and send it off to the final destination. If
   nServiceBus is built on top of MSMQ, then why is the application creating more
   queues and managing them?
3. I see absolutely nothing about Publish or Subscribe anywhere in the project. I guess it is relying on the socket to receive messages and if so then it is not really taking advantage of nServiceBus's queuing facility? Or am I lost...

If queues are needed and if I was to build this I will have one app writing to
the queue (Q1), another app reading from the queue (Q1) and changing the format
and inserting to another queue (Q2) and finally a third app reading from the
(Q2) and sending it off to the web service. What do you think?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see nothing wrong with opening a socket in `Run` in an `IWantToRunAtStartup`. It must somehow be required that the service can be reached through some custom protocol implemented on top of sockets.

Processing the incoming socket messages by immediately `bus.Send`ing a message is also the way to go - the greatest degree of reliability is achieved by immediately doing *the safest thing possible*: sending a durable message.

Performing the message translation in a handler and `bus.Send`ing the result in another message is ALSO the way to go - especially if the translation is somehow expensive and it makes sense to be able to pick up processing at this point if e.g. the web service call fails.

Making a web service call in a message handler is also be the way to go - especially if the web service call is idempotent, so it doesn't break anything if the message ever gets retried.

In other words, it sounds like the service correctly bridges a socket-based interface to a web service-based interface.

It sounds weird, however, that the service employs multiple queues to achieve this. With NServiceBus it would be entirely sufficient with one single queue: the service's input queue.

Comment: sorry totally new to nservicebus.
bus.Send the message to where?
Also, do you think the way i described the app if the app is utilizing the queuing facility of the nServiceBus at all?

From what I have learned is that nServiceBus creates queues for us whether client, server or publisher

Comment: To follow "the NServiceBus way", you let your handler or the `IWantToRunAtStartup` have an `IBus` instance injected. This instance can be used to send messages, and most of the time it should be sufficient to `bus.Send(message)`, relying on the endpoint mappings in app.config to specify the destination.

Comment: And you are right - when you're using NServiceBus it should not be necessary to create queues manually, as each service will create its own input queue.